# MVC Unable to find Assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

I'm running into an issue after updating the assemblies in my project. Previously I deployed MVC application which contain a reference of an assembly named `Core.dll` (One of my class library project).

Now in the newer version, I completely removed the dependency of `Core.dll` from my project and added new dependency `TrainingEngine.Core.dll` (new class library project).

But the problem is after deployed my updated application, there are several errors being logged that says

```
Unable to find assembly 'Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

And after further investigation, I came to know that this error raised from those users who previously had opened website on there browser and now when they refresh on there side, this error logged and the site is not responding to them. But if they delete there browser cache or use another browser, it works fine.

I'm not sure why it still looking for old assembly even though I deployed new version. I restarted the App Pool, also Recycle it and restarted the web server but nothing help.

Please suggest

Comment: What will happen if they refresh the page by Ctrl + F5 (cache refresh)?

Comment: @SeM same error. I even reproduce it on my local. And enable Fusion log and found out it's trying to load from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root`. I deleted everything from `Temporary ASP.NET Files` and do a clean projec but it still trying to load from the same location. Any thoughts

Comment: Where do you see this error?

Comment: After enabling the fusion log I hit refresh in browser and after a min it throws an error `Unable to find assembly Core.dll ..` Then I navigate to FusionLog directory and search for `Core` and when I open that file that is where it is logged

Comment: Is Core.dll still in a .config file somewhere? Like a web.config file adding assembly references for Razor views?